# How to import javascript style code to phpmyadmin?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

How can i import data like this separated by `,` to a mysql database?

```
data = [{
    "q": "some text",
    "a": "var1",
    "b": "var2",
    "c": "var3",
    "p": "1.jpg",
    "v": "a",
    "id": 1
}, {
    "q": "another question",
    "a": "var 2.1",
    "b": "var 2.1",
    "c": "var 2.1",
    "v": "a",
    "id": 2
}
```

The mysql database table is structured as the data with the columns: id / q / a / b / c / p / v

I've tried to import the data directly but it doesn't work?

Any advices?

Comment: When you say import, do you mean a script that converts this into a sql insert etc etc or someway to import this directly into phpmyadmin? (my understanding was that phpmyadmin only allowed .sql and .csv for imports)

Comment: Decode it, loop through the values and build your query seems like a reasonable approach...

Comment: Did you tried : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367325/importing-json-into-mysql

Comment: That's json. mysql has absolutely ZERO support for json, other than treating it like plain text. if you want to "import" it, you'd need something to parse the json and build an insert query from the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP/PDO it's just for a one shot insertion :

```
$json = '[{
    "q": "some text",
    "a": "var1",
    "b": "var2",
    "c": "var3",
    "p": "1.jpg",
    "v": "a",
    "id": 1
}, {
    "q": "another question",
    "a": "var 2.1",
    "b": "var 2.1",
    "c": "var 2.1",
    "v": "a",
    "id": 2
}]';

$datas = json_decode($json, true); // transform json to php array

$db = connect(); // you have to change this with your PDO connection

$dataset = array("q", "a","b", "c", "p", "v", "id");
foreach($datas as &$data){
  foreach($dataset as $elem){
     if(!isset($data[$elem]))
        $data[$elem] = "";
  }
  $req = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO table (q, a, b, c, p, v, id) VALUES (:q, :a, :b, :c, :p, :v, :id)");
  $req->execute($data);
}
```

Considere to lock the table before insertions and unlock after if there are a lot of rows.

Comment: It gives me an error `Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /home/..../json.php on line 21`                                                           This is the line: ` $req->execute($data);`

Comment: It's because the datas are not identicals. I edited my post to handle that.