# MySqli Inserting mass data

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am working on a PHP script that will be mass inserting data into a table.

I am using a prepared statement like this:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO clans(id, clanid, name, badge, status, playercount, score, requiredtrophies, warswon, warslost, warstied, location,warfrequency, exp, level, description, playerjson, lastupdate)
            VALUES ('', ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, now())";
$stmt = $con->prepare($sql); //prepare update statement

$stmt->bind_param('ssisiiiiiissiiss',$clanid,$name,$badge,$status,$playercount,$score,$requiredtrophies,$warswon,$warslost,$warstied,$location,$warfrequency,$exp,$level,$description,$playerarray);
```

After that I have a while loop that will be executing a lot of queries(hundreds of thousands or even a couple of million!) and the data in them is quite big! The playerjson is a huge json array.

The data will be received from a JSON response from a website API.

I looked at transactions but they ended up with a 502 Bad Gateway which I assume is because of too much data in memory. It isn't timeout problems because I handled them in nginx and `ini_set`

So what is the quickest way to mass insert large amounts of data?

Comment: Mysql's `LOAD DATA INFILE` will insert millions of records in a few seconds.

Comment: @Daan sounds epic. But what if the data isn't in a file? You see the data will be received from a JSON response from a website API.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/17367561/ and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html could help

Comment: If you're receiving the records one at a time, then you're probably going to need to insert them one at a time.  You can either write the results to file then use `LOAD DATA INFILE` or consider adding occasional commits to prevent memory exhaustion.

Comment: @Mr.Llama what's the best thing to do for figuring out how often to commit?

Comment: @ShivamPaw - That's entirely up to you.  Try a hundred or so.  If that hurts performance, try a few thousand.  Just keep playing with the numbers.  Almost anything would be better that not committing or committing after every `INSERT`.

Comment: Okay thanks @Mr.Llama

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is LOAD DATA INFILE.  Consider creating a file !

But in your case create a tempory table

```
create table clans_temp like clans;
```

and insert into that. THEN update the original in one query and delete the temporary table.

As far a i know that is the quickest way given the restrictions of the question.

Comment: What's the point of that? Why not insert directly into the main one??

Comment: Because inserting into an empty table is faster. Then you add  all records at once which is faster too. When you are talking thousands of inserts it makes sense.

Comment: Whoops.. i assumed you are using a table that is being used as well.