# Creating mysql tables from json file in django

Tags: mysql, json, django

I have exported data from firebase in one json file,I want to create a mysql tables using this json file.Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use MySql Workbench. It looks provide Json format to import.
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-admin-export-import.html

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could convert your json into csv and import that into mysql like it has been described here: [Importing JSON into Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367325/importing-json-into-mysql)

However, I am not really sure how that would be connected to django (since you mentioned it in your questions title). It might be helpful if you would describe in more detail what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

You can store data with very dynamic schema with Firebase. MySQL is a traditional RDBMS, you have to analyze the structure of your dataset and decide what parts do you want to convert to relational format.

There's a good news however: there are several packages which support JSON fields on models: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/json-fields/

There's one MySQL specific also: https://django-mysql.readthedocs.org/en/latest/model_fields/json_field.html

Such JSON data is queryable and updatable. So if your dataset has some varying schema parts, you can store those in JSON format.

Starting from MySQL 5.7 JSON data is even natively supported by the DB. Read more here:
https://django-mysql.readthedocs.org/en/latest/model_fields/json_field.html