# What programming language is this (newsfeed) and how would I go about getting it up on Wordpress?

Tags: json, ajax, wordpress, api

So I was given a link to a newsfeed by a colleague, and he wants it up on the Wordpress site I'm working on. I have no idea what this is and I have absolutely no idea what to do with it! The mind-blowing part is that he doesn't know what this is exactly either, yet he made it..

This is supposedly a list of news items:
http://www.slussen.biz/api/newslist/get?id=16

And this should be single news items:
http://www.slussen.biz/api/news/1146

What is this, and what can I do with it?

Super grateful for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't usually answer this kind of questions since it proves no sign of effort but I'll help you out.

The file you have received is a JSON document, containing lists of news that your client wants on his website.

To put it simply, it a file containing information structured as `key:value`. That JSON document contains a lot of information, it is called a JSON Array. Each element is called a JSON Object. JSON is used a lot because of its ease of use by various programs.

There are some ways to put that data on your database. Since your website is WORDPRESS, I'm sure that you can have access to a database administration panel where you can import that document. I suggest reading this thread:
 [Importing JSON into Mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367325/importing-json-into-mysql) on to how to import a JSON document to PHPMyAdmin. If that's not your database management platform, you can still do it manually in worst cases, just format it using any tool such as https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to have a clear view of how your data is structured.

Good luck.

Comment: Well thanks for taking the time to answer my question anyway, I am a beginner webdesigner, I'm well-versed in CSS and HTML (some jQuery) but stuff like this is like Mandarin to me.I made as much of an effort as I could, but I really didn't know what to search for.. because I really didn't understand any of it.

Thanks for helping a clueless noob out.

Comment: I feel like the fact that I don't actually have the file itself is going to be a problem, all I have is this link to the document on Their database. I can't just save it down manually because it's a dynamic ever-changing array (well it's news). Is there any way I could fetch the information from the external JSON array link and save it locally?

Comment: Maybe it is a web service? If that is the case, you have two option: 1. Develop it from server's backend, 2. Develop it from client side as a Single Page application. Either way, it is going to take some effort, a lot if you don't know what you are doing :(