# Persist large json string into database entries?

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, rest, jpa

I have a URL with a large number of entries that I want to persist into the MySQL database so that I can use my rest API to call on them. I have set up the whole structure as if im ready to use my own api, with entities, dtos, controllers, resources etc.

What I cannot figure out is, how do I persist json from the external api call into my database? Do I need to convert the json to entities before i persist them, or can I parse them directly into my database? And how would I go about persisting such a large json string with so many entries?

I've made an endpoint that calls the api, so that I can update the database on call, but I don't really know what to do next here

```
@PostMapping(value = "/popDB")
private itemEntity getItemObject() throws IOException {
    URL url = new URL("api url string");
    InputStream inputStream = url.openConnection().getInputStream();
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    Map<String, Object> jsonMap = mapper.readValue(inputStream, Map.class);
    articleService.save((ItemEntity) jsonMap);

    return (ItemEntity) jsonMap;
}
```

Comment: If you want to use JPA then yes you have to convert it to entities and then persist it

Comment: But if you don't need to use JPA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17367325/importing-json-into-mysql

Comment: Hmm, alright, thanks for the insight. I think figuring out a way to use JPA is better for me. Ill look into it, thank you.